# Adding months to date returns weird numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add months to my date but the result is pretty weird.

This is what I'm doing:

```
var date = new Date();
date = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 36);
```

and the outcome is:

```
1622458745610
```

I don't understand why...

Comment: check the Examples and Return value sections https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

Comment: Some methods like `Array.prototype.map` are *pure*, they don't modify the original. Some like `Array.prototype.sort` are *destructive*, calling them changes the target. The Date methods are mostly destructive. If you're used to pure ones, it can throw you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Date.prototype.setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) returns the number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date.

and you are equating it with `date` here

```
date = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 36);
```

so `date` has now the value returned by `setMonth`.

Use

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 36);
```

to set month for a specified date

Now log this to see the output:

```
console.log(date);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/utvjjm1d/ Okay, but why does it output that anyway?

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk the method *modifies the original*. Do the `.setMonth` on a separate line and log the `date` variable, not the result of the method call. See my edit to the answer. Also see my comment on your question.

Comment: Again you are logging the results of `date.setMonth`. Use it like explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

Comment: @george took the liberty of editing your answer to hopefully resolve OPs question.

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you!

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk no problem, return-value-vs-side-effects is confusing (and arguably unnecessary, but that's another topic). Please accept this answer (green checkmark).

Answer (score 3):

The result you are getting is the number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 and the updated date.

Convert it back to a date object like this:
    let d = new Date(1622458745610)

However, you don't need to retrieve the date as a variable. `setMonth` will mutate the date directly.

So just do:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 36);
console.log(date);   // Date 2021-05-31T11:06:54.215Z
```